Seaweed Farming on the ocean
I discussed with some friends the potential of seaweed farming on the ocean to fight climate change. We asked ourselves how the ecosystem would change when for example seaweed farms are present in the ocean. In a bad and a good way.
What does the ocean ecosystem look like? We know about phytoplankton, zooplankton, whales, fish, sea turtles, and so on.
Do you think seaweed farming on the ocean causes more good than bad to the environment?
Kind regards

Welcome to Biology SE! I'm afraid this question is probably too broad for this site. The ocean ecosystem is too complicated to cover in a SE answer and varies greatly geographically. In terms of sustainability, that will depend entirely on the specific practices used, but regardless I don't see how seaweed farming would sequester carbon. You might be interested in reading about integrated multi-trophic level aquaculture, which is sometimes touted for filtering seawater.

The planktonic algae are of more importance fighting climate change IIRC, there should be some literature around this - I think it's called ocean seeding and basically aims to add minerals to help the algae grow.
